# Watt & heat calculation

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity

this is my first post in this forum. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with physics and I hope I'm in the right place here. I asked myself how much energy I need to heat something.

I've found that by wattage you can figure out heat in Celcius.

So I researched the net and found that 1 watt is about 1.16194 C˙.
Then if a processor, as installed in my Mac, draws 65W, the chip would have to warm up to 55.94 C˙. But that's not true, because I measure temperatures of 105 degrees.

How exactly or what exactly am I doing wrong? For example, how can I find out how hot the surface of a light bulb draws 100W or in the case of a processor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I researched the net and found that 1 watt is about 1.16194 C

Technically not correct. The temperature difference is

$$\Delta T = T_2 - T_1 = Q \cdot R$$

where $T$ is the temperature in $^\circ\text{C}$, $Q$ is the generated heat power in $\text{W}$, and $R$ is the thermal resistance in $^\circ\text{C/W}$. In your case, temperature of the processor would be

$$\boxed{T_2 = T_1 + Q \cdot R}$$

where $T_1$ is the ambient temperature, $Q$ is heat generated by the processor, and $R$ is thermal resistance between the processor and the ambient. Note that ambient is actually the fluid that cools down the processor. For simple air cooling the ambient temperature is approximately equal to the room temperature.

From the data you have given us, the thermal resistance is $R = 1.16194 \text{ }^\circ\text{C/W}$ which means that for every $1 \text{ W}$ of generated heat power the temperature rises by $1.16194 \text{ }^\circ\text{C}$. For $Q = 65 \text{ W}$ of heat generated by the processor, the processor temperature would be

$$T_2 = T_1 + 75.5 \text{ }^\circ\text{C}$$

If the ambient temperature is about $T_1 = 25 \text{ }^\circ\text{C}$ the processor temperature is about $100 \text{ }^\circ\text{C}$, which is quite close to the measured processor temperature.

It must be noted that this model is overly simplified and you should not expect super-accurate results. In everyday engineering, anything within 5-10 $^\circ$C is considered to be good enough!

Comment: Great explanation of the missing steps and assumptions here.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: You really are a genius man. I couldn't find an answer like this anywhere without a joke.

Comment: @Lano I am glad it helped. I edited your original post a little bit - feel free to revert it to your original version if you feel it should :)

Comment: @MarkoGulin You have edited the question almost beyond recognition and to suit the kind of answer you've formulated. It's dishonest and I'm considering bringing this up on Meta. You also use terms that aren't very scientific, such as 'thermal resistance'.

Comment: “Thermal resistance” has a precise definition and is well understood as the heating per temperature difference, analogous to electrical resistance.

Comment: @Gert Feel free to report the issue to Meta or to a moderator. I am not going to comment the "terms that aren't very scientific", you have your downvote to express that you disagree.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Have you looked at the history of the question itself? By the time I had finished formulating an answer the question had been changed beyond recognition.

Comment: @Gert Apologies for having removed *"this is my first post in this forum. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with physics and I hope I'm in the right place here. I asked myself how much energy I need to heat something. I've found that by wattage you can figure out heat in Celcius."* If you feel this is necessary for your answer, feel free to do an edit of your own and bring back anything you think is important.

Comment: @Gert I certainly don’t disagree with your other points. Intended meanings should never be altered in edits.

Comment: @MarkoGulin Again, you are being disingenuous: you edited far more than that silly intro. Almost everything was changed. I've NEVER seen such an egregious edit at P.SE.

Comment: @Gert What are you trying to prove here? If I thought I was changing the original question (intention) of the author, I would have never changed it that way. It is perfectly ok to have a different opinion - why don't you revert whatever you think is necessary?

Comment: @MarkoGulin You might consider restoring the broader context of the title and restoring the content on light bulbs. You can address this aspect if you wish in your answer. It’s not fair to others working on answers to remove it.

Comment: @MarkoGulin If you can't see that such edits, followed by your own answer, will baffle some here then I can't help you. You even changed the TITLE! My own answer now looks like an answer to a different question altogether. I won't revert back because that will affect other answer including you. But I will raise a general issue on Meat. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for You, but "I've found that by wattage you can figure out heat in Celcius." is not true. Degrees give a state of a body, not its energy. 1 Watt is a measure of energy per time, so with about 4 watt you could change the temperature of   1 g of water by 1°C in 1 second so from 20°C to 21°C or from 7°C to 8°C
if your mac draws 65W   it depends very much how long You use it, how your processor is cooled, how warm the rest of its surrounding is. You will never be able to calculate the temperature by the watts.

Answer (score 1):

> I've found that by wattage you can figure out heat in Celcius.
>
> So I researched the net and found that 1 watt is about 1.16194 C˙.
> Then if a processor, as installed in my Mac, draws 65W, the chip would
> have to warm up to 55.94 C˙. But that's not true, because I measure
> temperatures of 105 degrees.

Unfortunately this completely wrong.

But it does take 'power' to **increase the temperature** of an object.

Firstly let's do some defining.

- power:

In physics power $P$ is defined as the ratio of energy to time. Assuming that in our case $P$ is constant in time:

$$P=\frac{\Delta E}{\Delta t}$$

where $\Delta E$ the amount of energy per time interval $\Delta t$.

E.g. a light bulb of $60\,\mathrm{W}$ uses (and radiates) $60\,\mathrm{J}$ ('Joule') per second of energy.

- temperature increase due to energy input:

Energy input to the object and temperature increase of the object are related as follows:

$$\Delta E=mc_p\Delta T\tag{1}$$

where $m$ is the mass of the object, $c_p$ the object's *specific heat capacity* and $\Delta T=T_2-T_1$ the temperature increase the object will experience.

$c_p$ (in $\mathrm{J kg^{-1}K^{-1}}$) is the increase in temperature if we add $1\,\mathrm{Joule}$ to $1\,\mathrm{kg}$ of object, in $\mathrm{Kelvin}$ (but here we can perfectly use $^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ - degrees centigrade)

---

So $(1)$ tells you what happens we we put a discrete amount of heat energy $\Delta T$ into an object but what happens is we put power, i.e. a continuous flow of energy into the same object:

$$\frac{\Delta E}{\Delta t}=mc_p\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta T}\tag{2}$$

This would seem to indicate that if we just keep up the power we could reach any temperature, right?

As it happens, also with your processor, most heated object do not only **receive** energy, they also **lose** energy.

This energy loss may be intended (cooled car engines e.g.) or circumstantial (your processor loses energy in a variety of way)

This loss of heat prevents the temperature of the object from rising and rising, so is actually much desired.

Some final, 'steady state' temperature will be achieved when:

$$P_{in}=P_{out}$$

**But it can't be found merely from input power.**